# How to integrate Oracle APEX and Alfresco via CMIS

Tags: rest, alfresco, oracle-apex, cmis

A question regarding the integration of the document management system Alfresco into Oracle Application Express (APEX) based on CMIs-repository:

The aim is to use APEX as the portal-page and Alfresco showing it's results (document lists) based on search parameters coming form APEX.
A search result from a CMIS-query should be displayed in an APEX page-region.
Unfortunately I have no experience in this sector (REST, CMIS) - so any advice would be welcome!
A related question regarding user authentication and authorization via CMIS does also arise.

Has anyone out there implemented something like this or used these components together, yet?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops into my mind is making the choice where you want your communication with the repository to take place: client side or server side?

Alfresco supports [Web Scripts](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/ws-architecture.html), so I would be possible to create a javascript-heavy thick client which connects to your repository, get information about your files and redirect to their download links.

The alternative would be to design some way to connect to the repository from the database server. Again there are many ways to do this. You can connect to the repository during your page load and use PL/SQL regions to fire scripts that connect to your repository, get the data you want, and render your region with that information.
Another way would be to periodically check the repository for changes, and maintain a 'shadow copy' of the repository within your oracle database tables.

Of course all of these solutions have their own drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you Bart! I'd prefer a server side (APEX+DB-Server) solution. APEX 4 provides a declarative wizard based method for creating references to RESTful style Web services. And I was hoping to use only this for querying Alfresco. I found an additional document at [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex40webservicesevaluationguide-214504.pdf) which also mentions an example using PLSQL (APEX_WEB_SERVICE_API). Right now it is a steep learning curve for me.